# How to insert a bash variable into a json string?

Tags: json, string, bash, variables, graphql

I have a bash script that does a post request to a GraphQL endpoint. The post body is JSON. Basically within that JSON, I would like to replace a value of one key/value pair with a value from a bash variable. I've tried different combinations but all of them resulted to errors. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

utc_format=$(date -v-2d -v-23H -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

curl -v \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-Auth-Email: email@email.com" \
    -H "X-Auth-key: $API_KEY" \
    --data '{"query": "query { viewer { zones ( filter: { zoneTag_in: [ \"abcde12345\" ] } ) { firewallEventsAdaptive ( filter: { source: \"waf\" datetime_gt: "'"\"$utc_format\""'" ruleId: \"100000\" action: \"simulate\" } orderBy: [ datetime_DESC ] limit: 100 ) { clientIP edgeResponseStatus metadata { key value } } } } }"}' \
    https://api.api.com/graphql \
    | python -m json.tool >> curl_results
```

If you look at my code, the "' at the end of datetime_gt is to close the '{" in --data. Then before rule_id, I opened it up again with '". What am I doing wrong?? I probably checked this a hundred times. Every time I try a different formatting, a new error pops up. Currently (with the code pasted here), the error that I get is:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "extensions": {
                "timestamp": "2020-12-21T03:32:11.090255834Z"
            },
            "message": "failed to recognize JSON request: 'invalid character '\"' after object key:value pair'",
            "path": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it works. At least you gonna have a valid JSON as output.

```
#!/bin/bash
utc_format=$(date -v-2d -v-23H -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

curl -v \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-Auth-Email: email@email.com" \
    -H "X-Auth-key: $API_KEY" \
    --data '{"query": "query { viewer { zones ( filter: { zoneTag_in: [ \"abcde12345\" ] } ) { firewallEventsAdaptive ( filter: { source: \"waf\" datetime_gt: \"'$utc_format'\" ruleId: \"100000\" action: \"simulate\" } orderBy: [ datetime_DESC ] limit: 100 ) { clientIP edgeResponseStatus metadata { key value } } } } }"}' \
    https://api.api.com/graphql \
    | python -m json.tool >> curl_results
```

Comment: No luck. It wants "" enclosing the date/time

 "message": "Syntax Error GraphQL (1:159) Expected Name, found Int \"-12\"\n\n1: query { viewer { zones ( filter: { zoneTag_in: [ \"e53a8b0cab5c66a53f51e09ee96a813f\" ] } ) { firewallEventsAdaptive ( filter: { source: \"waf\" datetime_gt: 2020-12-18T05:13:55Z ruleId: \"100173\" action: \"simulate\" } orderBy: [ datetime_DESC ] limit: 100 ) { clientIP edgeResponseStatus metadata { key value } } } } }\n

Comment: I was just gonna comment that I did that and it worked but you responded so fast haha. Anyways, thank you! You don't know how much you made my night.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help you out